# abstract class and anonymous class

Tags: java, abstract, anonymous-class

```
abstract class Two {
    Two() {
        System.out.println("Two()");
    }
    Two(String s) {
        System.out.println("Two(String");
    }
    abstract int  display();
}
class One {
    public Two two(String s) {
        return new Two() {          
            public int display() {
                System.out.println("display()");
                return 1;
            }
        };
    }
}
class Ajay {
    public static void main(String ...strings ){
        One one=new One();
        Two two=one.two("ajay");
        System.out.println(two.display());
    }
}
```

we cannot instantiate an abstract class then why is the function  **Two two(String s)** able to create an instance of abstract class **Two** ????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not create an instance of abstract `Two`. It creates a concrete, anonymous class that extends `Two` and instantiates it.

It's almost equivalent to using a named inner class like this:

```
class One {
    public Two two(String s) {
        return new MyTwo();
    }

    class MyTwo extends Two {
        public int display() {
            System.out.println("display()");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Stop pre-reading my mind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154740/abstract-class-and-anonymous-class/5154764#5154764)!

Comment: Is there a way to make MyTwo Anonymous?

Comment: @Usman Yes, that's what the original poster's question does.

Answer (score 2):

Because it implements the missing function display(). It returns an anonymous subclass of Two. You can see this if you look at the compiled files. You will have a One$1.class there, which extends Two.class!