# abstract class and anonymous class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [abstract class and anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154533/abstract-class-and-anonymous-class)

```
abstract class Two {
    Two() {
        System.out.println("Two()");
    }
    Two(String s) {
        System.out.println("Two(String");
    }
    abstract int  display();
}
class One {
    public Two two(String s) {
        return new Two() {          
            public int display() {
                System.out.println("display()");
                return 1;
            }
        };
    }
}
class Ajay {
    public static void main(String ...strings ){
        One one=new One();
        Two two=one.two("ajay");
        System.out.println(two.display());
    }
}
```

We cannot instantiate  an abstract class then why is the method **Two two(String s)** in class One returns an object of abstract class **Two**

Comment: if you don't understand the answers to the last time you asked the question, don't add the question again, add comments to the existing question.

Comment: Opps really very sorry for posting again.There was a bit of confusion at my end. I'll try to be careful in future

Answer (score 1):

As your question title suggests, you're instantiating an anonymous inner class that extends from Two, not Two itself.

Answer (score 0):

As your title suggests, the method `two()` creates an instance of an anonymous class extending `Two` (and implementing the `abstract` method `display()`.

This `One` implementation has pretty much the same result (except that the class is named now).

```
class One {
    public Two two(String s) {
        return new MyTwo();
    }

    private static class MyTwo extends Two {
       public int display() {
            System.out.println("display()");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```