# Android Studio abstract?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when I launch my app it crashes:

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnTouchListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
```

whitout `abstract` and `View.OnTouchListener` it works perfectly and. Why?

Comment: Are you actually trying to initialize an `abstract` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `override` the methods of `View.OnTouchListener` interface instead of making your activity as `abstract` so remove `abstract`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnTouchListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
   // other code and methods of NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Alternatively you can use `Add unimplemented methods` option from error help or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to view the list of unimplemented methods

Note : `abstract` class cannot be instantiated so read [Why can't an object of abstract class be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700256/why-cant-an-object-of-abstract-class-be-created)

Android OS will create an object of your launcher activity internally or it's also done while using `Intent` to start an activity

Reference

[`Abstract Classes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

[`Interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the methods for the interfaces you are using?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score -1):

When you add `implements View.OnTouchListener` you have to actually **implement** it.

When you declare it as `abstract` you don't implement the needed method.

This is: `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`

Info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Just add:

```
@Override 
public onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

}
```

And it will compile.