# Can we create object of Abstract Class? If no, why?

Tags: java

I have a abstract class B with two abstract methods

```
public abstract class B
{
    public abstract void C();

    public abstract void D();
}
```

I am trying to create the object of abstract class by using

```
B objB = new B(){

        @Override
        public void C() {

        }

        @Override
        public void D() {

        }};
```

Is `ObjB` an instance of Abstract class? Also I tried with `instanceof` operator as `System.out.println(objB instanceof B);` which is returning me `true`.

if the above is not the object of Abstract Class then why above statement is returning true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't an object of abstract class be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700256/why-cant-an-object-of-abstract-class-be-created)

Comment: Your code is incomplete so it is hard to see what you actually have in your code. If I understand correctly, you're creating a singleton of an anonymous (non-abstract) class (using `B objB = new B() { ... }`). `instanceof` will give you `true` not just for object's class, but also for any of its ancestors. So you have `B` (abstract) being extended by anonymous (non-abstract), being instantiated by `objB`.

Comment: From the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html): *"The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface."*

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't immediately instantiate an `abstract` class, the reason for this is: it is `abstract`.

In order to create an instance of such a class, you have to create a subclass, which provides an implementation for all abstract members of the class. 
Even if you haven't added any abstract methods, this still remains true.

```
instanceof
```

doesn't mean "This variable is of the type", but rather, this variable is of either this type, or an instance of a type that inherits from this type. So, on any object in Java: 
`myObject instanceof Object` will, if myObject is instantiated, return true, no matter the actual type of myObject.

The closest you can get to instantiating an abstract class without creating a concrete and named child class, is by creating an anonymous implementation:

```
B object = new B() {
            @Override
            public void C() {

            }

            @Override
            public void D() {

            }
}
```

The above block, as you did it, is not a direct instantiation of the abstract class.

It's the creation of a new class, for which you didn't provide a name, and instantiation of that.

Comment: "will return true, no matter the actual type of myObject." Unless it is null!

Comment: @AndyTurner Good point.

Comment: "without creating a child class" I think it is misleading to imply this doesn't create a child class. It's not using the `class` keyword, but it most definitely does create a class, and then causes instances of that class to be created at runtime.

Comment: I indeed had some ambiguity in my explanation, as later I stated: "It's the creation of a new class, for which you didn't provide a name, and instantiation of that."