# Java Abstract Classes

Tags: java, class, object, abstract, concrete5

When dealing with abstract classes in Java it is not possible to create an object of that class.

So this would not work `AbstractClassName object = new AbstractClassName();`.

Why this is working `AbstractClassName object = new NonAbstractClassName();` ?

Can you tell me what am I doing by using a constructor from a non abstract class (that extends the abstract one) and assign the object to a abstract class type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700256/why-cant-an-object-of-abstract-class-be-created

Comment: You can achieve loose coupling by this. You can assign any class object inheriting from `AbstractClassName`.

Comment: Related: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface/384067).  Same concept when programming to an abstract class.

Comment: That is polymorphism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Thanks for you help guys. I found the magic word : "loose coupling".